# Meaning of "PC" in "PC Engine"?

Tags: terminology, turbografx-16

In Japan, the TurboGrafx-16 was known as the "PC Engine".  What did the "PC" stand for?  Presumably it was not Personal Computer?

Comment: Why presumably not "personal computer"? It's personal and it's a computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*PC* literally just means personal computer - a computer owned by a person rather than an organization like a corporation, university, or computing club. The term is roughly synonymous with *microcomputer* with an additional implication of a price point measured in thousands (or less) rather than tens of thousands of dollars. Contrasting terms are *mainframe computer* or *minicomputer*, describing systems physically too large for most individuals to own.

The contraction of *IBM PC* to just *PC* took place in the early 90s as the IBM PC (and more importantly, IBM-compatible PCs) came to dominate the personal computer market.

That market shift was not inevitable in 1987 when the PC Engine was released, and the domination didn't happen in Japan until even later (where you saw IBM PCs but also a lot of NEC PCs).

Comment: [This part of the Japanese Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3#%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A2%E6%A7%8B%E6%83%B3) comments on the concept, though I don't know what source it's citing.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [these pictures](http://nfggames.com/games/pce_protos/), the PC Engine was meant to sit in the center of a case or housing for a personal computer.

Comment: I do not see the connection to a IBM PC compatible computer. Those images portray prototypes. The PC Engine is a console with a fast 8-bit 6502 processor variant and 16-bit graphics graphics chips. If one stumbles over a picture of a PCE and PC, the PC is usually a development machine for game developers.

Comment: "None of this hardware was released, although as you can see the CD ROM and Monitor devices
 at least made prototype stage."  This pictures are displaying the intended consumer use of the PCE, not the dev experience.  Also, they do not connect to an IBM PC, but rather are the center of their own PC.

Answer (score -4):

Because often Japan likes the look and sound of Western names for things rather than the name actually meaning anything. Also probably to give it connotations of power and expandibility. And because it's a less stupid name than TurboGrafx.

Comment: This is … wild guessing? Or do you have any reference that this concrete product was named for it’s spoken sound, and not in fact PC being an acronym?

Comment: It's no more of a wild guess than either of the other two answers.

Comment: May be true, but doesn’t make it better. And may change, with adequate answers.

Comment: Which part of my answer do you think I'm guessing about? I'd argue it's all common knowledge for anyone above a certain age, but I'm pretty sure I can source everything in it...